# RSU taxing moving from NJ to WA

Tags: income-tax, new-jersey, washington

If I have an offer for a job in Seattle, but I will initially be in NJ before moving, how will RSU taxes be affected? Will I have a long term impact from being in NJ briefly before moving to a no income tax state?

Comment: Will any RSU vesting occur while you are still a resident of NJ?